# wordpress wp_enqueue_style on page that doesnt include get_header

Tags: wordpress

I have created a plugin which has it's own custom page template. I dont want this apge to use the default themes css, so have excluded `get_header()`, and used the following which just pulls in the wordpress functionality

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php'); global $wpdb, $woocommerce;
```

My problem now is i am trying to enqueue a style, but as my template is not including `get_header(`) or `wp_head()` it doesnt look like it is working. Is there a way around this?

I am using wp_enqueue_style like this:

```
function woops_styles() {
wp_register_script('packing-slip', plugins_url('/my-plugin/style.css', __FILE__));
wp_enqueue_script('packing-slip');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'woops_styles' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to include `wp_head()`, so you will need to have a header. `wp_enqueue_scipts` hooks on `wp_head()`.

What I would suggest if you need a diffirent styling for this page is to assign a `body_class()` to this page and then style that accordingly. You can use a conditional statement (`is_page_template()`) to only assign the `body_class()` to this specific page template.

If you really don't need a header to show up, simply hide it with css